# Foursquare API venues search returns empty venues

Tags: java, android, json, geolocation, foursquare

I'm writing an Android app using Foursquare APIs. I'm trying to make a request to this URL:

```
    String url = "https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?ll=16.31503,38.973039&"
        +"client_id="+CLIENT_ID+"&client_secret="+CLIENT_SECRET+"&limit=25&v="+date;
```

where date is formatted in YYYYMMDD. I actually have a response, but the `venues` array is empty:

```
{
    meta: {
        code: 200
    }
    notifications: [
       {
         type: "notificationTray"
         item: {
             unreadCount: 0
         }
       }
    ]
    response: {
        venues: [ ]
    }
}
```

Why is it empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I confused longitude with latitude and vice versa. My mistake! Thank you (:

Answer (score 1):

This is because there unfortunately isn't much in the area you're searching in. Take a look at the result from running the same search on the web: https://foursquare.com/explore?near=16.31503%2C38.973039 (zoom out a bit to see where there are results)

Comment: It seems strange to me! If i try to check in from that location (is where i am now) from the foursquare app, i have some suggestion! How can i have the same results?